# Transitive Dependency doesn't work properly

Tags: maven

I am trying to configure a general POM that will contain some basic dependencies that probably all my projects are going to use.
I made a project with POM.xml,with packaging set to pom and added some basic dependencies.
Then i am trying to add this project as a dependencies using this code in my project:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.arslan</groupId>
            <artifactId>general-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I expected that NetBeans would automatically start downloading the depedencies of the dependency(transitive depedencies),but it doesn't.This whole thing works fine with inheritance,but i wanna try it without inheritance — just to see it works...What could be the problem?I run install on the general-deps project so that it's available in my local repository.

Comment: Usually the transitive dependencies will only work if you have a `<type>jar</type>` or a like but a `<type>pom</pom>` will not work cause a `<packaging>pom</packaging>` will never has code nor will it create a jar file which  can be used on the classpath nor on the module path. What you can do is to create a bom file (pom with dependencyManagement) and use that I recommend to read https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: @khmarbaise I thought that bundling dependencies in a POM and referencing them as above would be a standard Maven way. A BOM will only manage versions, but if you have, say, five runtime dependencies that you need in 50 projects, you can put those five in a POM and use it in those 50 projects.

Comment: I was reading Maven the complete reference,the authors were writting that you can do so,because when you depend on another project,your project receives transitive dependencies of the project you depend on.In order to do that,do i have to make the project that contains dependencies jar packaging? And why POM packaging doesn't work,since POM means that it s going to be in my local repository?Even if it a project doesn't use its dependencies/libs,they are still downloaded in the local repository